# App Update Android Studio Version name and Version code

Tags: android-studio, build, release, google-play-console, in-app-update

For App Update , which i need to change version code or version name in android studio

```
  minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 11
    versionName "11"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some tips from this resources:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350?hl=en
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

I hope these will help you:

When you're ready to make changes to your app, this article describes what you need to do to make sure that existing users receive your update.

**Prepare your updates**

- The package name of the updated [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/) must be the same
  as the current version.
- ***The version code must be greater than the current version***. Go to the
  Android Developers site to learn more about [versioning your app](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).
- The updated app bundle must be signed with the same signature as the
  current version.